# How can I combine HTML tags and a variable inside .html() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable representing a filename, and I intend to insert an html image with that filename into a div like so:

```
$("#s_premise_description").html("<img src="scenario/images/" + myVariable + " />");
```

Except that obviously isn't working, but it hopefully explains what I'm trying to do.

I imagine an easy work around is just creating a variable like so:

```
var imgURL = "<img src="scenario/images/" + myVariable + " />";
```

Then using imgURL as the value for .html(), but I would think there's another way, and my syntax is just wrong.

edit: So before refreshing my question I fiddled around for a moment, and tried single quotes and it seems to be working.

Now everything appears to be working. There are a lot of different ways of handling the quotations posted here, so thanks everyone for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
var imgURL = "<img src=\"scenario/images/" + myVariable + "\" />";
```

or

```
var imgURL = '<img src="scenario/images/' + myVariable + '" />';
```

Comment: or use single quotes to define the sting, which is better for readability (IMO)

Answer (score 3):

You must escape double quotes inside your strings, or use single quotes:

```
$("#s_premise_description").html("<img src=\"scenario/images/" + myVariable + "\" />");
```

Or:

```
$("#s_premise_description").html('<img src="scenario/images/' + myVariable + '" />');
```

Comment: Result: `<img src="scenario/images/"foo.jpg />`

Comment: Yup, you're right. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

your are missing quotes, use this :

```
 $(target).html("<img src='scenario/images/" + myVariable + "' />");
```

its will work .

Answer (score 1):

you're getting tangled in your quotes:

`$( "#s_premise_description" ).html("<img src="scenario/images/" + myVariable + " />");`

should be something like this:

`$( "#s_premise_description" ).html("<img src='scenario/images/" + myVariable + "' />");`

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape your quotation marks like so:

```
$("#s_premise_description").html("<img src=\"scenario/images/" + myVariable + "\" />");
```

Or you can just use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to do so:

```
$("#s_premise_description").html("<img src='scenario/images/" + myVariable + "' />");
                                           ^                                  ^
```